# Определение широты и долготы

Tags: android

Пишу приложение, где надо определить широту и долготу для работы с картой. Мой код:

```
    listener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            locationLat = location.getLatitude();
            locationLon = location.getLongitude();
        }
    };
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
            300000, 
            10, 
            listener);

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
}
```

Вот. Если я захожу с самсунга, то все координаты определяются нормально. А с сони координаты всегда нулевые, т.е. код не работает. Или может код и работает, только широта и долгота нулевыми приходят. Хотя даже включены настройки определения местоположения и присутствует проверка

```
   isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
```

В чём может быть дело?

Comment: сторонние приложения (например google maps) показывают координаты?

Comment: человек, у которого сони мне пока не отвечает на этот вопрос) но точно знаю, что это уже второй человек с сони, на котором происходит такое)

Comment: может у него в настройках отключен GPS?

Comment: он сказал, что включал и gps и определение с помощью беспроводных сетей.

Comment: мало чего, может он в бункере и спутники не ловит.

Comment: ладно, спасибо) было бы хорошо, если так)

Comment: @KoVadim, если бы спутники не ловило, то ивентов об обновлении местоположения бы не отсылало...

Comment: Писал точно такой же код, на Lenova постоянно 0.0, хотя в приложении от гугл определяется нормально